# How to convert `const std::vector<T*>` into `std::span<const T*>`

Tags: c++, c++20, std, std-span

Title.

I am implementing this class:

```cpp
#include <span>
#include <vector>

class MyClass {
public:
    std::span<int *> numbers(void) {
        return m_numbers;
    }

    std::span<const int *> cnumbers(void) const {
        // What to do here?
    }

private:
    std::vector<int *> m_numbers;
};
```

My first attempt was to use the automatic conversion exhibited in the non-const function (I believe this has something to do with `std:decay`? I don't really understand it).

```cpp
return m_numbers
```

This fails to compile, with no known conversion.

One implementation I've found is this:

```cpp
return std::span(m_numbers.begin(), m_numbers.end());
```

this returns a `std::span<int * const>` though, which is not exactly what I want. Variations of this using `cbegin` do not seem to help.

I'm targeting c++20

Comment: What happens if you use `return std::span<const int *>(m_numbers.begin(), m_numbers.end());`?

Comment: Same as the first approach: `error: no matching function for call to <full typenames>`

Comment: Okay, what about if you use `return std::span<const int *>(m_numbers.cbegin(), m_numbers.cend());` to try and propagate the const through?

Comment: You're trying to break `const`-correctness - `std::vector` propagates `const`-ness. You should return `std::span<const int * const>` instead.

Comment: @Evg that's it. Updating the return type to `std::span<const int * const>` allows me to just write `m_ints`. If you give an answer I'll mark it correct

Comment: You also probably want the non-const overload of `numbers()` to return `std::span<int* const>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to break const-correctness. Returning `std::span<const int *>` would've allowed modification of those elements (pointers themselves, which won't be `const`).

The correct return type should be `std::span<const int * const>`, note the additional `const` at the right.

Comment: Perhaps worth clarifying that `const int *` means a pointer to a const int. The pointer itself can change, but not the value it points to. Whereas `int * const` means a pointer that cannot change to an int that can. The `const int * const` type makes both aspects `const`.

Comment: The `const` member function has nothing to do with it, actually.  The owner of the `vector<int*>` can write to the targets of its pointers, and as a result it can only store pointers to writable `int` objects.  So even a non-`const` member function cannot permit modifying the vector elements with pointers to read-only objects.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'll try to improve answer wording, thank you for the comment!

Comment: Technically a way to get the `std::span<const int*>` would be to use `auto begin = const_cast<const int**>(m_numbers.data()); return std::span<const int*>(begin, begin + m_numbers.size())`. 
But it breaks const-correctness, and may cause UB if the caller modifies the pointers.